# H2 intermittently experiencing a StackOverflowError when first hitting the database

Tags: java, h2

Once in a while our H2 database (v1.4.199) throws a `StackOverflowError` internally when our Java Spring Boot application starts and hits the database with a very simple `SELECT` query against a single table, which is the *first* query of the app. The application will eventually start correctly, but only after several restart attempts, each one throwing the same `StackOverflowError`. Given it eventually does work this does not feel like a true infinite recursion problem.

Here is the stacktrace from the `h2.trace.db` logs:

```
2021-08-02 13:46:15 database: flush
org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.StackOverflowError [1.4.199/3]" [50000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$1.uncaughtException(MVTableEngine.java:90)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.handleException(MVStore.java:2787)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.panic(MVStore.java:441)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.store(MVStore.java:1194)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.tryCommit(MVStore.java:1135)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2763)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:3123)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.StackOverflowError [1.4.199/3]" [50000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.StackOverflowError [1.4.199/3]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.transfer(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2415)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.addCount(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1070)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1619)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$ChunkIdsCollector.registerChunk(MVStore.java:1620)
    [invoking registerChunk() continues for another 1000 lines before being cut off...]
```

The `StackOverflowError` is wrapped as a `IllegalStateException` which is then captured in *our* application logs as this stacktrace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from nio:/home/myapp/database/h2.mv.db failed; file length -1 read length 768 at 55238818159 [1.4.199/1]" [50000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:313) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.prepareConnection(AbstractQueryRunner.java:319) [commons-dbutils-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.execute(QueryRunner.java:851) [commons-dbutils-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.database.objectstores.h2.AppCache.<init>(AppCache.java:46) [main/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.ObjectStore.database(ObjectStore.java:41) [main/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.ObjectStore$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5cc3c27.CGLIB$database$0(<generated>) [main/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.ObjectStore$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5cc3c27$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$94399cde.invoke(<generated>) [main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

The `file length -1 read length 768 at 55238818159` error in our application is exceptionally concerning.

We are running our H2 database (v1.4.199) in file mode with the following configuration in our Java Spring Boot application:

```
    String url = "jdbc:h2:file:~/database/h2;"
            + "DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;"
            + "AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;"
            + "DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;"
            + "MODE=MYSQL;";    
    
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .username("sa")
        .url(url)
        .driverClassName(org.h2.Driver.class.getName()).build();
```

Our database has 10 tables and each table acts like a key/value store with a few `VARCHAR` columns acting as composite unique key and then a `CLOB` that often holds large JSON data. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
  keypart1 VARCHAR,
  keypart2 VARCHAR,
  keypart3 VARCHAR,
  json_value CLOB,
  primary key (keypart1, keypart2, keypart3)
)
```

Most tables have a few hundred or few thousand records with smaller `CLOB` values, while our biggest table has 20k records with `CLOB` values ranging from 2mb to 120mb (the average is 4mb). The `h2.mv.db` file is about 50GB.

The application has been working fine for 2 years until this problem started. It looks like `registerChunk(MVStore.java:1619)` in the stacktrace is where H2 is traversing parent/child chunks of data, so I'm wondering if it was freeing space, fixing some kind of earlier corruption, or our massive `CLOB` data is throwing it off somehow.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. First, the `IllegalStateException` is a red herring, so I focused on the `StackOverflowError` instead. It looks like H2 v1.4.199 has some poor recursion logic in `MvStore` that starts to fail when the database passes a certain size or complexity threshold. By increasing the stack size from 256K (default) to 10MB with the JVM `-Xss10M` argument, H2 was able to recurse deep enough to successfully finish the startup logic.

I have also seen this `StackOverflowError` cause other types of `IllegaStateException` such as the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to connect to H2
    at com.myapp.migrate.H2Db.<clinit>(H2Db.java:36)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This store is closed [1.4.199/4]" [50000-199]
```

As well as the original error I encountered:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from nio:/home/myapp/database/h2.mv.db failed; file length -1 read length 768 at 55238818159 [1.4.199/1]" [50000-199]
```

This `StackOverflowError` appears to be the root cause of different failures but is rethrown/rewrapped as something else.